#  Double screen doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, randr

i can't solve a problem with my screen configuration.

I tryed in anher italian forum, but i haven't find a solution.

In my configuration i have an nvidia geforce 480x.
I'm trying to use 2 screen, for work, and with ubuntu 11.10 i was using already this configuration, and the only problme was ane error message at the start up, but nothing else.

Now i can't use 2 screen without error.
First of all i want eliminate the upper bar from the second screen, but when i try to open the monitor configuration an error appears and sad that the RANDR extension is not present...and when i boot the system ubuntu notify me that he encountered a system error!!!

I've tryed both twinview and separeted screen, but none of them work at well...
I can't believe that a thing that work so easy in windows can't work at well also in ubuntu, so please help me!!

Thanks.

PS: This is a link with an image of my 2 screens
http://www.obit8.com/Errore.png Consider that for now i don't have anymore the error about the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set it in the  nvidia-settings program.

For me the nvidia driver is so bad that i removed the nvidia-driver and use nouvau now. Much faster and more stable.. But in your case the card is probably not supported nicely.

Comment: I set all the configuration trough the nvidia settings program, this is the problem.
Where i can check if my card is supported!?

Comment: You can start here: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix . But your card is very new and i think some features are not supported. In any case, you can try to use it and revert to nvidia-drivers if you do not like the result.

Comment: I'm trying to download other drivers from nvidia support, my card is a GTX 480...i don't thinki is so new...i mean, at least 2 years!