# Revert screen settings on changed by Jupiter

Tags: jupiter

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and used Jupiter for Betty performance. I have selected "Video displays" to External display only with my Account. My display gone just a black screen.

How can I recover my display?

Comment: Do you have nVidia? Then have a look at this for starters, it is about updating the video drivers.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/134335/double-screen-doesnt-work

Comment: as I told I am new user of ubantu, can you please tell me how can i remove jupiter from my guest account or some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login to your account. Use the command `sudo apt-get remove jupiter` and reboot your computer with `sudo reboot`.

Your screens should be back to default.

Comment: No it is not listed in softwares. with my Guest account

Comment: guest-expVVx@raza-Aspire-5749:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
guest-expVVx@raza-Aspire-5749:~$

Comment: As i posted the commads in last comment .. I am unable to run sudo command in my guest account.

Comment: Can you recall what method you used to install Jupiter in the first instance??

Comment: thanks Sun Dial... I have removed the Jupiter and then install. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this. For those finding this thread now:
At login screen, ctrl+alt+f1 (Brings up terminal mode)
Login using username/password

```
sudo rm -r /var/jupiter/
```

Then alt+F7 to return to login screen.